# Is INotifyPropertyChanged supported by Mono?

Tags: .net, mono, inotifypropertychanged

I'm currently developing an application that should be able to run under the standard .Net Framework as well as under Mono. I was wondering if I could safely implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my business model and that the Mono Framework would pick it up without extra effort?

Is the support of data binding good enough in the Mono Framework in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Mono supports their [Windows Forms implementation](http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms) quite well, including data binding.  Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your business objects should work well with Mono and their databinding.